# Where clause concat with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write what I thought would be a simple where clause. The FULLNAME string is formatted like this ("Doe, John"), hence the where clause and concat function.

Here is the query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE concat(LAST_NM, ', ', FIRST_NM)  = FULLNAME;
```

The query fails with the following error:

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver] 
>   [SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Add your concat statement to your select, see what the results look like. And what error are you receiving?

Comment: mysql or sql-server, which one is it? They are different.

Comment: concat returns null if any are null; you may need to use ifnull syntax to avoid this

Comment: What errors are you getting? I tried this query and it works for me.

Comment: @perplexedDev heres the error i'm receiving: Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 0):

Is your FullName something like "Doe, John"?
Is your FullName complete?

if not

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE concat(LAST_NM, ', ', FIRST_NM) like ('%' + FULLNAME + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not see anything wrong with your query, I would like to suggest a way to troubleshoot, by trying to find if it is a specific raw values that cause the concat function to break.

The idea is to iterate through the raws printing each one's values so you'll know which one (if at all) fails it, and it might be easier to take it from there to the next step.

```
--Copy your table data to a temporary table
--E.g. 
SELECT  *
into #table
FROM    
(
    select 'Doe' as LAST_NM , 'Jhon' as FIRST_NM
        union
    select 'Ryan' as LAST_NM , 'Jack' as FIRST_NM
        union
    select 'Dylan' as LAST_NM , 'Bob' as FIRST_NM
) a

--Iterate through the rows to see which one causes the issue
DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @TableCount INT = (select count(*) from #table)
DECLARE @FN varchar(100)
DECLARE @LN varchar(100)

WHILE @I <= @TableCount
BEGIN
    SET @FN = (select Top 1 FIRST_NM from #table)
    SET @LN = (select Top 1 LAST_NM from #table)
    print(@I)
    print(@FN)
    print(@LN)
    print('------------------')
    delete top (1) from #table  
    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

Comment: thanks, this helped alot. I ended up having to go with a subquery to get the result I needed!

Comment: `so you'll know which one (if at all) fails it` – fails what exactly, though? The issue is a syntactic error, it can't possibly have anything to do with data given the information provided. @JET1991 Although it may be irrelevant now, could you tell me what version of SQL Server you are using?